# apt-get update failure returns 0 error code

Tags: ubuntu, apt, exit-status

When we run apt-get update and if it fails, a non zero error code should be returned, but in my case its still 0. See below:

```
root@ubuntu-base:/home/user# apt-get update
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://packages.siawai.com:8085 trusty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://packages.siawai.com:8085 trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'packages.siawai.com'
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.siawai.com:8085/repos/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.siawai.com:8085/repos/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'packages.siawai.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@ubuntu-base:/home/user# echo $?
0
```

What could be the issue? I am running ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: "Could not resolve ..." suggests a problem with DNS

Comment: Yes, its a network failure created on purpose. The issue is with the return code. Why is it not non zero

Comment: "_When we run apt-get update and if it fails, a non zero error code should be returned_". Is that "_should_" as in "the documentation tells me so" or as in "I expect it to do so"?

Comment: _should_ as in "_everyone_ expects it to do so". This behavior is just ridiculous. So many setup scripts, Docker images etc. are just one "transient" network failure away from silently installing an old version of a package without noticing, due to this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional; see [#778357](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=778357):

> The results are meaningful. 0 indicates success or transient error, whereas
>   other values indicate a persistent error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Transient errors? What causes it? Or how can it be fixed? Here I just removed internet access from a VM and run apt-get update. It returns non zero error code on other ubuntu VMs, but this one is returning 0.

Comment: I am mostly concerned why its returning 0 in this VM only.

Comment: A transient error refers to an error which will fix itself at some point, in all likelihood — basically, `apt-get update` returns non-zero only if human intervention is needed. If you’re seeing varying behaviour from one VM to another, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: By default it returns non zero, thats why it was not mentioned in the question

Comment: I also noticed `Reading package lists... Done`. Meaning something successful has happened. May be thats why it returned 0. What causes `Reading package lists... Done`?